# Prevent duplicate insertion based on two columns in a table

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3-python

I have a table with below columns and trying to insert values real time.

```
TableName: ML_data
```

ref:

```
  s.No colA colB colC colD
   1   xxx  123  7   9   
   2   yyy  345  9   4
   3   xxx  456  3   5
   4   xxx  123  6   5
```

possible duplicates of above table are rows 1 and 4 with colA colB having similar values. I want to restrict my insert when such data occurs in sqlite3 with unique constraints on colA and colB.

Also is there a way to catch the error and not stop my insertion process  in the real time.

tried:

```
alter table ML_data add unique index(colA,colB);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ON ML_data (colA,colB);
```

You may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html (i.e. there is no `ADD INDEX` ability)
And also https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: this ignores if any of the column has duplicates. But then i am looking if two columns values have duplciates, like row 1 and 4 has same values, but 3 has different value

Comment: @pylearner NO the index will create a UNIQUE conflict when inserting or updating a row. When this occurs the insert will IGNORE that conflict if it is an `OR IGNORE`, perhaps you want `OR REPLACE` which will update the row. However, the issue you had was that you **CANNOT use ALTER TABLE to add an index** , you have to create the index.  If you do not want *I want to restrict my insert when such data occurs in sqlite3 with unique constraints on colA and colB.* then should have asked the question without saying so.